# Rails Has_one and has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relationships, single-table-inheritance

I have Teacher model:

```
class Teacher < User

  has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :grades, through: :categories
end
```

Grade model:

```
class Grade < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teachers, through: :categories

end
```

Category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :grade

end
```

Student model:

```
class Student < User

end
```

Now i want to set up relationship between Grade model and Student model
(student has_one grade and a grade has_many students) with through model Category.
How can i do this?

Comment: Yeah sort of...

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to use a single join table `Category` for associating students to grades AND teachers to grades. Either you're confused about what associations you need, or I'm confused about what real-life relationships you're trying to represent. If students are simply assigned to a grade, why not use student `belongs_to :grade` and grade `has_many :students`. Why are you trying to join _through_ the `Category` model? What is a `Category` in real life?

Comment: Category is just a through table for many to many relationship between grades and teachers .. so I'm thinking to use same through table to set up relationship between grade and students .

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student < User 

  has_one: :grade

end
```

and

```
class Grade < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teachers, through: :categories
  has_many :students, through: :categories

end
```

and

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :grade
  belongs_to :student

end
```

Does the above not work..? You should put what you have tried in your post if you have run into issues.

Comment: Thanks.!! But doesn't need to write anything in Category model?

Comment: Whoops its the end of the work day for me so I'm drained- You probably need a belongs_to in Category too. I will edit my response now 

As a side-note, the shoulda-gem is really helpful in testing your associations and making sure they work as intended- I would look into it if you are having trouble verifying that you set up your models correctly. Each association can be done with one line in a spec file using the gem. I highly recommend.

Comment: Doesn't i need to write this 
 has_one :category
 has_one :grade, through: :category
in student model?

Answer (score 0):

Join tables are for many-to-many relationships. Since a student only has one grade, it is a many-to-one relationship, not a many-to-many relationship.

You do not need (and shouldn't use) a join table for this.

Instead add a `grade_id` column to the students (users) table and setup the associations like this:

```
class Student < User
  belongs_to :grade
end

class Grade < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :students
end
```

Don't use any `through` associations to connect students with grades.